# как перебрать массив и вывести его данные в нужном месте на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

к примеру есть массив с данными , вот эти данные нужно вывести в нужном месте , я так думаю методом сравнения по дате

```
 // данные о событиях
    var dataNot = [
     { "date": "68", "title": "Событие 1", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "123" },
     { "date": "610", "title": "Событие 2", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "" },
     { "date": "610", "title": "Событие 3", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "123" },
     { "date": "613", "title": "Событие 4", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "643" },
    ];
```

вывести эти данные нужно в div

```
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="610"></div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="613"></div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="68"></div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="69"></div>
```

данные из массива где параметр ***date*** сравнивается с атрибутом div ***aria-label***  и если они схожи то подставляются данные именно по этой дате.
как можно такое реализовать может кто знает или сталкивался с этим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dataNot = [{
    "date": "68",
    "title": "Событие 1",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set",
    "url": "123"
  },
  {
    "date": "610",
    "title": "Событие 2",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set",
    "url": ""
  },
  {
    "date": "610",
    "title": "Событие 3",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set",
    "url": "123"
  },
  {
    "date": "613",
    "title": "Событие 4",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set",
    "url": "643"
  },
];

const comparison = (arr) => {
  let divArr = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  let temp = document.querySelector('#temp').content;

  for (let i of divArr) {
    for (let j of arr) {

      if (i.getAttribute('aria-label') == j["date"]) {
        let newTemp = temp.cloneNode(true);
        let ul = newTemp.querySelector('ul');

        ul.children[0].textContent = 'date: ' + j["date"];
        ul.children[1].textContent = 'title: ' + j["title"];
        ul.children[2].textContent = 'description: ' + j["description"];
        ul.children[3].textContent = 'url: ' + j["url"];
        i.appendChild(newTemp);
      }

    }
  }
}

comparison(dataNot)
```

```html
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="610"></div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="613"></div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="68"></div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder" aria-label="69"></div>
<template id='temp'> <!-- Шаблон -->
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </template>
```

Если я правильно понял, чего вы хотите...